# Having trouble finding this limit

Tags: calculus

**The original question is:**

$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+Δx}-\sqrt{x}}{Δx}\right)$

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. I multiplied by the conjugate, simplified the numerator, canceled out Δx, and am left with $sqrt$(x+Δx) + $sqrt$(x), do I plug in "0" for the x's or did I do something wrong? I'm trying to understand this so steps would be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, once you have simplified to a limit that does not evaluate to $\frac{0}{0}$ you can directly substitute and get the right answer.

Comment: It sounds like you simplified the expression correctly. All you have to do now is plug in $0$ for $\Delta x$

Comment: I was about to ask, do you mean $\Delta x\to 0$ instead of $x\to 0$?

Comment: Do you really mean to make $x \to 0$ ? I ask because if instead Δx goes to zero it is the definition of derivative of $h(x)=\sqrt{x}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would calculate it in the following way.
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h} &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x+h-x}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\\
\end{align*}